# Jersey- Rest: 404 not found error

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am doing a simple program , the task is to Get (user id)  from html form over Rest  and username associated with should be displayed. I am
getting a 404 error when I load the index.html page.

But when i give the values(userid)  over the url it works fine.

here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/rest/my/first/rest/users" method="GET">
        <label for="uid">ID</label>
        <input name="uid" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the resource class

```
@Path("users") //attach client request to resource: .../users
public class RestResource {

    Map<String,User> listUsers;  

    //initialize some resources
    public RestResource(){
        listUsers = new HashMap();
        listUsers.put("1",new User("1", "John"));
        listUsers.put("2",new User("2", "Peter"));
    }

    //return list of users
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String listOfUsersInText(){
        String list="";
        for (Entry<String,User> u:listUsers.entrySet()){
            list += u.getValue().getName() + "\n";
        }
        return list;
    }

    //return user information corresponding to the requested uid.
    @GET
    @Path("{uid}") //attach client request to resource: .../users/<uid>
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getUID(@PathParam("uid") String uid){

        if (!listUsers.containsKey(uid))
            return "User not exist!";

        return listUsers.get(uid).getID()+":"+listUsers.get(uid).getName();
    }   
}
```

WEB.xml

```
 <display-name>rest</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>my.first.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The approach you have followed is wrong we have several rest client api's you can use any of those and can send the request to rest resource**

**The response data you can display in jsp pages.**

Comment: okey. But I guess that should not be the reason to  get an error? I am not able to view the index.html page. what could be the reason for this ?

Comment: where did you place the index.html inside Web-INF or out side??

Comment: it is placed outside the WEB-INF folder, It is in the Web Content folder.. Is the path address in form action correct?

Comment: when you submit the form by giving input the request will be submitted to rest resource there rest resource will not return any response or page redirection so will get error 404

Comment: But i am not able to view the request page itself (i.e) index.html

Comment: how you are running that html page post the url here!